# creating pp3 point pattern in spatstat for a cone-shape point cloud

Tags: spatstat

How can I create a 3D point pattern (PP3) in spatstat package for a point cloud which does not have a cube/rectangular cube shape (for example, cone or tetrahedron)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is only possible to use a three dimensional box as the domain of a three dimensional point pattern, and I don't expect this to change anytime soon.